# Handle Back button with Angular [Chrome]

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome

I am creating a project using angular, In my application I need to handle back button event. Below is the code which is working fine apart from one scenario

Code:

```
this.location.subscribe(event => {
 //logout
});
history.pushState({}, '');
```

This code only works when user is perform some activity, if user just landed on page and click back button then this event is not captured. I tried all the ways but not works.

Comment: what do you need to handle back button exactly for? If you use the router as the primary source of truth I see little cases where you'd need that

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to add the `popstate` event, every time when user click on the back button. It will be fired.

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', (event) => {
    // The popstate event is fired each time when the current history entry changes.

    // logout or do any thing you like

}, false);
```

If this doesn't work you could go for Angular Router and check which event is called.

```
constructor(router: Router) {
    router.events
      .subscribe((event: NavigationStart) => {
        if (event.navigationTrigger === 'popstate') {
          // Perform actions
        }
      });
}
```

Comment: Not working when directly click on back button without any activity

Comment: Where did you add this code exactly?

Comment: in app.component.ts file

Comment: Yes, try to add that in `ngOnInit()`, it should work. Try to add a console in the event and check the console. It is simple to add and test, I just did that it works.

Comment: No, its not woking, only work when user do some activity like click or anything

Comment: Yes, How do you think a popstate is captured? When user clicks only at that moment you can catch it else it is not feasible.

Comment: It is working in firefox not in chrome

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/8721521/disable-back-button-on-browser?hl=en

Comment: Check the above updated answer.

Comment: No, Not Woking, i think chrome is allowing to capture the pop event without user activity

Comment: What is happening? Does it throw an error or working at diff events?

Comment: no error, it just refresh the same and that event is not triggered

Answer (score 0):

This solves the problem for me, captured even when no activity by user

```
@HostListener('window:popstate', [$event])
onPopState(event: any) {
  console.log('Event', event);
}
```

**PS**: tested in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override the whole `onpopstate` like this

```
window.onpopstate = function () {
  // Your logic should be here...
}.bind(this); // This line is to bind the components
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that before the user interacts with the web page, `beforeunload` is fired and the page will be unloaded before you can catch `popstate`. Combined together, they seems to be working.

Note that you won't be able to completely override browser behavior as a security feature.

https://angular-ivy-pbvgpj.stackblitz.io/

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  backButtonClicked = false;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
  }

  @HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event']) onClickBack(
    event: PopStateEvent
  ) {
    history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
    this.backButtonClicked = true;
  }

  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event']) onBeforeUnload(
    event: BeforeUnloadEvent
  ) {
    history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
    this.backButtonClicked = true;
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pbvgpj?file=src/app/app.component.ts)